# MPAndroidChart how to set label color?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

got the following code:

```
    graph = (LineChart) convertView.findViewById(R.id.graph);
    graph.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_LEGEND_LABEL).setColor(Color.BLUE);
    graph.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_YLABEL).setColor(Color.BLUE);
    graph.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_XLABEL).setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

But still the color of X/Y-value-lables and also the lable of the legend stay in black color. Do I miss something? Is there an other way to set the color of these?

This line for example works and results in blue value-lables for each data-point:

```
    graph.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_VALUES).setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this to set the colors of axis and legend:

```
chart.getAxisLeft().setTextColor(...); // left y-axis
chart.getXAxis().setTextColor(...);
chart.getLegend().setTextColor(...);
chart.getDescription().setTextColor(...);
```

If you want to set the color of the drawn values inside the chart, check out the [setting colors](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/colors/) documentation or the [setting data](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/setting-data/) documentation.

Comment: Hi!
This solution works with getXLabels and getYLables, but getLegend() returns null. But I can clearly see the legend indicating the color of my graph and a lable next to it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Read the documentation of the getLegend method

Comment: @PhilippJahoda is there a way to set the color for each x axis label? This was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772646/mpandroidchart-can-i-set-different-colours-for-the-x-axis-labels?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Hi Phiip, I am appending the label and value while setting to piechart but I want to increase the size of the value to bold.Can we do that ?

Comment: getLegend()  does the job

Comment: @AshishShukla to make the x axis bold use 

line_chart_to_draw_weight.getXAxis().setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));

Answer (score 4):

Incase for a pie chat to change its label colors you can do this

```
pieChart.getLegend().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```