# MPAndroidChart: Can I set different colours for the x-axis labels?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

So I want to be able to select a bar in my bar chart, and when I select a bar, it changes the colour of the bar (which I know how to do), but also change the colour of the corresponding x-axis label. Is there a way to do this, if so, can someone help me please?

Comment: Refer to these [#139](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/319) and [#387](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/387) issues. Also, look at these questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632489/mpandroidchart-how-to-set-label-color and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888850/mpandroidchart-set-different-color-to-bar-in-a-bar-chart-based-on-y-axis-values. I expect that a combination of them will help you to get it (I do not know if it is really possible or not, but maybe you can do some workaround with that data).

Comment: @Error404 none of those links help for the question asked

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it is possible to set different colors for the xAxis labels. You will have to use a custom renderer, something like below:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.XAxisRenderer;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.MPPointF;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Transformer;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Utils;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ViewPortHandler;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by rawsond on 29/01/17.
 */

public class ColoredLabelXAxisRenderer extends XAxisRenderer {

    List<Integer> labelColors;

    public ColoredLabelXAxisRenderer(ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, XAxis xAxis, Transformer trans) {
        super(viewPortHandler, xAxis, trans);
        labelColors = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }

    public ColoredLabelXAxisRenderer(ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, XAxis xAxis, Transformer trans, List<Integer> colors) {
        super(viewPortHandler, xAxis, trans);
        this.labelColors = colors;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawLabels(Canvas c, float pos, MPPointF anchor) {
        final float labelRotationAngleDegrees = mXAxis.getLabelRotationAngle();
        boolean centeringEnabled = mXAxis.isCenterAxisLabelsEnabled();

        float[] positions = new float[mXAxis.mEntryCount * 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i += 2) {

            // only fill x values
            if (centeringEnabled) {
                positions[i] = mXAxis.mCenteredEntries[i / 2];
            } else {
                positions[i] = mXAxis.mEntries[i / 2];
            }
        }

        mTrans.pointValuesToPixel(positions);

        for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i += 2) {

            float x = positions[i];

            if (mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsX(x)) {

                String label = mXAxis.getValueFormatter().getFormattedValue(mXAxis.mEntries[i / 2], mXAxis);
                int color = getColorForXValue(mXAxis.mEntries[i / 2]); //added

                mAxisLabelPaint.setColor(color);

                if (mXAxis.isAvoidFirstLastClippingEnabled()) {

                    // avoid clipping of the last
                    if (i == mXAxis.mEntryCount - 1 && mXAxis.mEntryCount > 1) {
                        float width = Utils.calcTextWidth(mAxisLabelPaint, label);

                        if (width > mViewPortHandler.offsetRight() * 2
                                && x + width > mViewPortHandler.getChartWidth())
                            x -= width / 2;

                        // avoid clipping of the first
                    } else if (i == 0) {

                        float width = Utils.calcTextWidth(mAxisLabelPaint, label);
                        x += width / 2;
                    }
                }

                drawLabel(c, label, x, pos, anchor, labelRotationAngleDegrees);
            }
        }
    }

    private int getColorForXValue(int index) {
        if (index >= labelColors.size()) return mXAxis.getTextColor();

        if (index < 0) return mXAxis.getTextColor();

        return labelColors.get(index);
    }
}
```

Consume it like this:

```
mChart.setXAxisRenderer(new ColoredLabelXAxisRenderer(mChart.getViewPortHandler(), mChart.getXAxis(), mChart.getTransformer(AxisDependency.LEFT), colors));
```

where `colors` is a `List<Integer>` of resolved colors (not resource ids) the same size as the number of entries in the `IDataSet`. Since you already know how to change the color of the bar on a highlight, that part is up to you. Just manipulate `colors` in the same way you would normally. Here is a sample output:

[image: bar chart with colors matching the bars]

Comment: Very helpful! Sorry for taking long to validate it.

Comment: Hi am trying to use this code but there is something missing MPPointF etc...How can i get this code

Comment: @SunishaSindhu which version of MPAndroidChart? The answer here works for MPAndroidChart 3.0.1 and above

Comment: @DavidRawson can i also do it via click to change the color?